# Store value of regex match in a variable

Tags: regex, matlab, parsing, regex-group, regex-negation

I have a string that contains a timestamp and some random characters.  For example, `str = "11:05:46 some random text here"` and I just want to grab the timestamp and store it in a variable using regex.

The regex for the timestamp format is

```
\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
```

and I am using regexp on Matlab like this:

```
timestamp = regexp(str,expression)
```

where str is `"11:05:46 some random text here"` and expression is `'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'` but it is returning the index (1) and not the value itself (`11:05:46`).

Is there a way on Matlab that I can get the value and store it in a variable when the value matches a regex expression? expected output: 11:05:46

Or is there a way where I can just match everything else but the timestamp? expected output: some random text here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `'match'` as the 3rd argument to the `regexp` function:

```
timestamp = regexp(str,expression, 'match')
```

Output:

```
timestamp =
{
  [1,1] = 11:05:46
}
```

The `'match'` argument makes Matlab output *text of each substring that matches the pattern in expression*, see [documenation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html).

Using [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) you may remove the timestamp at the start of the string to return all that remains:

```
>> regexprep(str,expression,'')
ans =  some random text here
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. I have also used regexprep to replace the timestamp with a space but I do not want to rely on that. Is there a way to negate the timestamp regex so that it only captures a certain group, lets say, letters a-j? I know it does not make sense to capture letters and ignore the timestamp, but I just want to learn how to put those 2 logics together. I was thinking something like (^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(a-j) but this does not capture a-j because my syntax is lacking.

Comment: @HaiHey You may capture all after a timestamp: `expression = '\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*(.*)'` and then use `tokens = regexp(str,expression,'tokens')`